# 7 days hourly mean with pandas

Tags: pandas, mean, rolling-computation

I need some help calculating a 7 days mean for every hour.

The timeseries has a hourly resolution and I need the 7 days mean for each hour e.g. for 13 o'clock

```
date, x
2020-07-01 13:00 , 4
2020-07-01 14:00 , 3
.
.
.
2020-07-02 13:00 , 3
2020-07-02 14:00 , 7
.
.
.
```

I tried it with pandas and a rolling mean, but rolling includes last 7 days.
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: @Malik , what is your expected output from the above input? Can you post that?

Comment: Expected output should be the 7 days mean of each hour: e.g. at 13 o'clock (4+3+4+6+3+7+3)/7. So it must be something like a rolling mean which includes always the last 7 days at current time.

Comment: So in your example, rows 1 and 3, the answer would be `3.5 `and rows 2 and 4 it would be `5`?

Comment: sorry it is a misunderstanding, from all values at 13 o'clock at the last 7 days the mean should be calculated and of course from all values at 14 o'clock and so on. And always for 7 days, so you have always 7 values which build the mean. I hope it is a bit clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new `hour` column, grouping by `hour` column, and then add
The average was calculated over 7 days. This is consistent with the intent of the question.

```
df['hour'] = df.index.hour
df = df.groupby(df.hour)['x'].rolling(7).mean().reset_index()
df.head(35)

   hour level_1 x
0   0   2020-07-01 00:00:00 NaN
1   0   2020-07-02 00:00:00 NaN
2   0   2020-07-03 00:00:00 NaN
3   0   2020-07-04 00:00:00 NaN
4   0   2020-07-05 00:00:00 NaN
5   0   2020-07-06 00:00:00 NaN
6   0   2020-07-07 00:00:00 48.142857
7   0   2020-07-08 00:00:00 50.285714
8   0   2020-07-09 00:00:00 60.000000
9   0   2020-07-10 00:00:00 63.142857
10  1   2020-07-01 01:00:00 NaN
11  1   2020-07-02 01:00:00 NaN
12  1   2020-07-03 01:00:00 NaN
13  1   2020-07-04 01:00:00 NaN
14  1   2020-07-05 01:00:00 NaN
15  1   2020-07-06 01:00:00 NaN
16  1   2020-07-07 01:00:00 52.571429
17  1   2020-07-08 01:00:00 48.428571
18  1   2020-07-09 01:00:00 38.000000
19  2   2020-07-01 02:00:00 NaN
20  2   2020-07-02 02:00:00 NaN
21  2   2020-07-03 02:00:00 NaN
22  2   2020-07-04 02:00:00 NaN
23  2   2020-07-05 02:00:00 NaN
24  2   2020-07-06 02:00:00 NaN
25  2   2020-07-07 02:00:00 46.571429
26  2   2020-07-08 02:00:00 47.714286
27  2   2020-07-09 02:00:00 42.714286
28  3   2020-07-01 03:00:00 NaN
29  3   2020-07-02 03:00:00 NaN
30  3   2020-07-03 03:00:00 NaN
31  3   2020-07-04 03:00:00 NaN
32  3   2020-07-05 03:00:00 NaN
33  3   2020-07-06 03:00:00 NaN
34  3   2020-07-07 03:00:00 72.571429
```